# QML TextField how to capitalize the text

Tags: qml, capitalization, capitalize

In QML how can I have a text input box that automatically converts the inputted text to all capitals? The following doesn't work:

```
    TextField {
        id: myfield
        objectName: "myfield"
        ...
        font.pixelSize: 20
        font.capitalization: Font.AllUpperCase
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just made a typo in the name of the constant which should be `Font.AllUppercase` with a lower `c`. If you look at your logs you should see a warning like this:

> tsttxtfield.qml:22: Unable to assign [undefined] to int